# Google messing up with messages that go through the SMS-email gateway

Tags: google, sms

I have a small web application -- a prompter that tells people when they should be ready to come live on a meeting -- that works well on e-mail. It sends people a message (periodically) saying they are about 15 min (or less) to go in, and offers them two links to click.

1. One where they should click to confirm all is okay.
2. Another where they could ask not to be sent any further messages

It all works nicely on e-mail and and people interact with it to let the schedulers know everything is okay for them to go live.

Recently we start sending some to TXT messages via [e-mail to SMS gateways](https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6356597) and we noticed that every time a message goes by GoogleFi gateway. Google reads (or parses) the content of the message and (absurdly) clicks on both links as they traverse the gateway... rendering the notification useless.

I know of many services that will check all links on an e-mail and encapsulate them, example are [ProofPoint](https://proofpoint.com) that prevents target attacks, but in this case the URL was not encapsulated.

Why would Google do that? Meaning touch the link?